# Regular expression to check non-escaped charcters

Tags: c#

Many characters, like ellipses, quotation marks, long hyphens, apostraphes, superscript, and subscript will all be encoded incorrectly as boxes and strange text characters when we are submitting the web page.We need to make a regex expression which will check for these characters.

Actully when we would submit things like quotation marks, or ellipses, or bullet points, they would show up as a big square on the web page  or they would be escaped out and be a string of control characters, like $&&$.
so, we want to find or check for those squares, control sequences, and other strange unicode character types.

so we need  regular expression that check all these. Or is there any other way or approach that we should follow.

Comment: if you are using regex to validate text, do not try to validate all characters. filter for acceptable characters and disallow everything else. [a-zA-Z0-9_-] plus other characters you want to allow and nothing else.

Comment: `We need to make a regex expression which will check for these characters`. As @Veronica said, it is most probably an encoding issue. Try to fix it that way before using Regex

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of the squares depends on the Encoding that you use to read. If you are using ASCII encoding you will see squares instead of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit for alphanumeric and numeric characters and also let like underscore and dash you can replace other character or remove them.

```
@"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]"
```

This is a Regex that match all characters which are not a to Z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and -, _.

You can than replace all other characters with underscore for example.

```
 string newStringParsed = Regex.Replace(stringToParse,  @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "_");
```